# How to send false boolean value from Attribute Converter to Database as null or 'N'

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, converters

My scenario is something like below, wherein, I have AttributeConverter as below which is mapped to indicator column, Lets say FRUIT_IND which can contain values null, 'Y' or 'N'

```
import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import javax.persistence.Converter;

@Converter
public class BooleanToCharAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<Boolean, Character> {
```

Which has a convertToDatabaseColumn method taking either true/false as input and check the column value in database.

```
@Override
    public Character convertToDatabaseColumn(Boolean booleanValue) {

        if (booleanValue) {
            return 'Y';
        } else {
            return 'N';
        }
    }
@Override
    public Boolean convertToEntityAttribute(Character charEntered) {

        if (Objects.nonNull(charEntered)) {
            if(Character.valueOf('Y').equals(charEntered)) {
                return true;
            }else {
                return false;
            }

        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Now my problem is we have some data which is populated from other stream, and it still has values as null. But when try to fetch reports using JPA methods to get all records which has FRUIT_IND as false it is failing to get any (Which is expected since most of the FRUIT_IND are null because of migrated data)..

Can I in any modify this converter to fetch records which have null or 'N' in the same way ? OR Is there any way to do it at hibernate end to treat null and 'N' as one and the same.

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: It sounds like you might have a misunderstanding of what JPA Attribute Converters do for you. A converter simply tells your JPA framework *how* to convert a column of data from your database table into a property of a Java object and back again. Nothing more. It absolutely *does not* play any part in *querying* for said data.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I understand the logic behind the JPA Attribute Converters here but my question is more about how can we fetch records from DB which have values null or 'N' with the help of converters or in any other way using hibernate.

Comment: That was my point, you say you want to "fetch records from DB which have values null or 'N' with the help of converters" - *that's not what converters do*. Converters aren't involved in querying data, they come into play once the data has already been fetched and needs to be transformed into Java objects. Don't get me wrong, there **are** ways to achieve what you need, but a JPA converter isn't a tool that will let you achieve it.

Comment: It would be useful if you could include the code that you're using to query the data, including the JPQL query if you're using one, or the Criteria query if you're using those instead. That will be where the changes need to be made.

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from your question is that you want to fetch the results from DB where FRUIT_IND is null or N with the JPA.

For that, you can define a method into your repository which is extending JPARepository.

```
returnType findAllByFruit_ind(String fruit_ind);
```

The things to remember-  In method name the fruit_Ind should be same as the name in the entity class.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, But we already have a JPA find method `entityReturnType findByIdAndFruit_ind(1,false);` which actually when fetching checks for 'N' flagged records in database but we have value as null there because of which it is failing

Comment: can you clear about your table by sharing a db snippet !

Comment: @PrasannaKumar update the query and include a `or FRUIT_IND is null`